# Grab data from a different table when two values doesn't match and replace the existing value

Tags: sql, database

I need to convert a Unit measure value in a database view when two criterias doesn't match with information from a different table. So what I do have is one database view called "v_Purchase order" table and one table that is called "Alternate unit" table.

[image]

As you can see in the example I have 3 rows in the Purchase order table, where Purchase order U/M and Basic U/M match on 2 rows, but not on the third row. So what I wish is that: 
case
when (Purchase order U/M <> Basic U/M)

then (use Alternate unit table to replace Purchase order U/M column row from Purchase order table with the Alternate U/M from the Alternate unit table and apply the Conversion factor to multiply it with Quantity to convert pallet to pieces)
else(No conversion needed)
end

The two tables are joined on Item number, Company, Alternate U/M

Which should give me this final output result:
[image]

```
ALTER VIEW v_Purchase order
Item number,
Company,
Quantity,
Alternate U/M,
Purchase order U/M,
Basic U/M
FROM Purchase order
```

All Ideas and help are very much apprieciated
Best regards,
Rubrix

Comment: Looks like a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Hello @jarlh I wish to convert the exisitng row in the v_Purchase order so that the Quantity gets multipied with conversion factor in the Alternate U/M table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select a.itemnumber, a.company, 
       case when purchaseorderUM<>basicUM then quantity*conversionfactor else quantity end as quantity, 
       a.alternateUM, 
       case when purchaseorderUM<>basicUM then b.alternateUM else purchaseorderUM end as purchaseorderUM, 
       basicUM
from Purchaseordertable a left join Alternateunittable b 
     on a.itemnumber=b.itemnumber and a.company=b.company
```

Comment: But the Quantity column row also needs to be converted using the conversion factor as you can see in the example. It feels like I need a cte or a subquery to be able to accomplish the calculation/conversion ?

Answer (score 2):

A `LEFT JOIN` is appropriate but you can refine it by only looking for matches on rows where the purchases numbers do not match.  Then, you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
select po.itemnumber, po.company, 
       coalesce(po.quantity * au.conversionfactor, po.quantity) as quantity, 
       coalesce(au.alternateUM, po.purchaseorderUM) as alternateUM,
       po.basicUM
from Purchaseordertable po left join
     Alternateunittable au
     on po.itemnumber = au.itemnumber and 
        po.company = au.company and
        po.basicUM <> po.purchaseorderUM;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon,
Thank you for your response and help. This solution seems very neat and refined. I will absolutely test it out. It is Always great when you have multiple solutions for one problem and you can play around with them.

Comment: @Rubrix . . . You should ask a new question.